# Form submitting despite validation LINQtoSQL

Tags: validation, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL data annotation validations. I get the validation messages if some fields are invalid. However if I hit save, the form still submits (with the invalid values).

View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<div id="Content">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
....
....

<input type="button" id="btnSave" name="submit" value="Save" />

$("#btnSave").on("click", saveRecord);

function saveRecord() {

//document.forms[0].submit();
$.ajax(
 { type: 'Post' ,
     url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Orders")',
     data: {
         OrderID: '@Model.OrderID',
         ShipName: $('.Name input').val(),
         ShipAddress: '@Model.ShipAddress',
         RequiredDate: '@Model.RequiredDate',
         ShipPostalCode: '@Model.ShipPostalCode'
         },
     dataType: "html",

         success: function  (data){
             //alert ('saved');
              }
     })
return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're not actually 'submitting' the form, you're just making an ajax post of the form's contents, so any validation logic hooked into the form's 'submit' event won't fire.

You'll probably need to add a guard to prevent the ajax post from occurring unless the form is valid, ie something like:

```
var myForm = $('form');
myForm.validate();
if(myForm.valid()) { //Assuming that valid() is the method provided by your client side validation library.
    $.ajax(...)
}
```

You should also be validating the data again when it is received by the server (before you insert it into the database) to stop people from deliberately circumventing the validation on your web page.

Also, this question probably shouldn't be tagged with linq-to-sql, as it appears to be purely an issue with jQuery validation & ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations.

Comment: Try `$(document.forms[0]).valid()` (I'm assuming you're using the jQuery validate library)

Comment: Actually, this is what I tried first. Now I tried the one in your answer. Error: object [object object] has no method valid.

Comment: Ah, apparently `validate()` needs to be called before `valid()` can be called. [See here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/). I've updated by answer to reflect this.

Comment: Error: object [object object] has no method validate.

Comment: 1. If `$().validate` and `$().valid` aren't defined, then the validation libraries aren't loaded on the page. 2. What object is being returned by `$('form')`?

Comment: It just says object [object object]. Must be the form object itself. I am trying to figure out why the validation libraries arent being loaded on the page.

Comment: Ok, I have got the validation to work the first time. However when an ajax call is made (e.g. clicking next/previous), the validation doesnt work.